# How can the function lambda access to my loop or loop using kivy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to Kivy and Python and i am trying to develop an application that is based on Instagram Layout interface.

First i defined a class ImageButton that will make me create a image button:

```
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass
```

Then i used this class to create image button in a grid.
here is my Code :

```
class AllImage(BoxLayout):
    # screen_manager = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        BoxLayout.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'
        self.sizable_from = 'top'
        splitter = Splitter(sizable_from = 'bottom')
        root = ScrollView()

        gridtest = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=10)

        layout = GridLayout(cols=4, spacing=10)


        self.add_widget(splitter)
        super(AllImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for im in IMAGES_NAMES:
            if IMAGES_NAMES != None :
                btn = ImageButton(source = im+'.png')
                btn.bind(on_press=  lambda a:gridtest.add_widget(ImageButton(source = im+'.png') ))

                layout.add_widget(btn)


        splitter.add_widget(gridtest)
        root.add_widget(layout)

        self.add_widget(root)
```

My current goal is to add the ImageButton in the grid `layout`to the grid `gridtest` when i press on the imagebutton.

The problem i am encountering now is`btn.bind(on_press=  lambda a:gridtest.add_widget(ImageButton(source = im+'.png') ))`

When i press the ImageButton i don't have the image i pressed in the 2nd grid but the last image in the 1st grid.

I think the problem come from lambda because it don't have the access to my loop and i can't do a loop on it.
So what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closures in Python (which you are creating with the `lambda` here) are late binding, the value is looked up when the function is invoked (in effect, using the last value for the loop variable if defined in a loop).

The solution is to pass `im` as a default argument:

```
lambda a, im=im: # rest same
```